# One to Many relationship, sort and filter children

Tags: mysql, laravel, relationship

I want to display all posts which like the user. OK. I can use this:

```
$user = User::where('slug', $user->slug)
                  ->first();
dd($user->likes);
```

But it doesn't what I want to do. Which any post have to be accept by moderator (->where('accept', 1)) and orderign (->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')).
Who know how I can do that?
Currently I have 2 models. My relationships:

```
//Post
    public function likes(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
//Likes
    public function post(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
//migrate of likes look like this
        Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Do you at least have a `User` model?

Comment: I solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an M:N relationship between User and Post using Likes as pivot.

```php
# User model
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Likes::class, 'user_id');
}

public function liked_posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'likes', 'user_id', 'post_id');
}
```

```php
# Likes model
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

You could set it up like you have, User has many Likes belongs to Post.

```php
// Using only likes and Likes's post relationship
$user = User::with(['likes.post' => function ($posts) {
    $posts->where('accept', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Or you could use the M:N relationship.

```php
// Using the liked_posts relationship
$user = User::with(['liked_posts' => function ($posts) {
    $posts->where('accept', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```